# How to know scrapy-redis finish

Tags: scrapy

When I use scrapy-redis that will set spider DontCloseSpider.
How to know scrapy crawling finish.

crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed,signal=signals.spider_closed) not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

I see this comment:

```
# Max idle time to prevent the spider from being closed when distributed crawling.
# This only works if queue class is SpiderQueue or SpiderStack,
# and may also block the same time when your spider start at the first time (because the queue is empty).
SCHEDULER_IDLE_BEFORE_CLOSE = 10
```

If you follow the setup instructions properly and it doesn't work, I guess that at least you would have to give some data that allows to reproduce your setup e.g. your settings.py or if you have any interesting spiders/pipelines.

`spider_closed` signal should indeed happen. Just quite some seconds after it runs out of URLs in the queue. If the queue is not empty, the spider won't close - obviously.